# Why my android phone no function after add the Tab Bar View for Custom Scroll View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't know why my android setup phone will show black screen and cannot click, is someone else can help me solve the problem? I try many ways for it but still no function for these codes. Maybe because I am a new coder for the Flutter, so maybe I cannot find my ways myself. For these code, I want to set the `CustomScrollView` to let the app bar can be scrolled up when scrolling.

```dart
    return DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                leading: new IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {}, icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp)),
                title: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'My Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        EditProfilePage();
                      },
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.create_outlined))
                ],
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                shadowColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 3,
              ),
              SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 150,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        // physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          buildProfile(user),
                          Divider()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 1,
              )),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: const TabBar(
                              labelColor: Colors.black,
                              indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "PERSONAL DETAILS",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "FINANCE DETAILS",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "PARTICULAR OF DETAILS",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: TabBarView(
                          children: [],
                        ))
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

Here is my image for this problem

[image]

image before adding Custom Scroll View and this is the final design

[image]

and now this is my new problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXXik.png)

--The code for the profile--

```
Widget buildProfile(User user) => Container(
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          ),
          ProfileWidget(
            imagePath: user.imagePath,
            // onClicked: () {
            //   Navigator.of(context).push(
            //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditProfilePage()),
            //   );
            // },
          ),
          buildName(user),
        ]),
  );

 Widget buildName(User user) => Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      // InkWell(
      //   onTap: readLoading == false
      //       ? () {
      //           getData();
      //         }
      //       : null,
      //   child: Container(
      //     height: 50,
      //     width: 80,
      //     color: Colors.blue,
      //     child: Center(
      //       child: readLoading == false
      //           ? const Text(
      //               "Get",
      //               style: TextStyle(
      //                 color: Colors.white,
      //               ),
      //             )
      //           : const CircularProgressIndicator(
      //               color: Colors.white,
      //             ),
      //     ),
      //   ),
      // ),
      Text(
        user.name,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
      ),
      Text(
        "Senior Developer\n",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
      ),
      Text(
        user.email,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
      ),
      Text(
        "014 2353 6777",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
      ),
    ],
  ));
```

Comment: Add any code you made for this

Comment: Ok, I add already because this is my first time to use stackoverflow

Comment: Its render problem you have used SilverList inside Column and Expanded for Tabview. Check below answer i have added SliverFillRemaining outside to slove the tabview

Answer (score 0):

User SliverFillRemaining Class instead of Expanded,

```
 return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            leading: new IconButton(
                onPressed: () {}, icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp)),
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                'My Profile',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // EditProfilePage();
                  },
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.create_outlined))
            ],
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            shadowColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 3,
          ),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    // physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      // buildProfile(user),
                      Divider()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: 1,
          )),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: const TabBar(
                          labelColor: Colors.black,
                          indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "PERSONAL DETAILS",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "FINANCE DETAILS",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              child: Text(
                                "PARTICULAR OF DETAILS",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              childCount: 1,
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Tab 1"),
                Text("Tab 2"),
                Text("Tab 3"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying me and I copy your code but it still got problem for showing 'no material widget found',  Is I lost someting to download? And for the sliver list, the design for the word has default for red color and the font family?

Comment: The code which i updated is working fine in my device by commenting // buildProfile(user) and // EditProfilePage();. Since you have not updated your complete code in question so it difficult to find the problem where you have missed

Comment: Ohh I sorry about that, I have reload in my question and the picture that current facing. The buildProfile(user) I also add in and the EditProfilePage() actually is a null function because not yet design just a onverter page. Thanks